# Server related file paths for .js in OpenShift project

Tags: javascript, external, openshift

I am working on a Codeigniter project on Openshift. I want to get the use of external .js files in my project. I have included those in public folder. My folder structure is as followed

[image: Folder strcuture]

And I have imported the .js files as bellow

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>JointJS/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>JointJS/lib/jquery.sortElements.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>JointJS/lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>JointJS/lib/underscore.mixin.deepExtend.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>JointJS/lib/backbone.js"></script>
```

But i do not get the result and the firebug report tells that the .js files cannot be found. How can I access  (give the address) .js files. All required .js files are inside the **public** folder. Is there any thing to change in .access file. If 'yes' what should my .access file look like ?

Comment: can't you just use path or root relative paths on the script urls?

Comment: How can I use root relative paths?

Comment: /public/JointJS/lib/underscore.js or maybe just /JointJS/lib/underscore.js, it's hard to say exactly from where i'm sitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the .js file using just relative path.Use following to access

```
<script src="public/JointJS/lib/jquery.js"></script>
```

It worked for me